# Private Set but still can Add

Tags: c#

I have this specified interface:

```
public interface IMyInter
{
   ObservableCollection<Data> files{ get; }
}
```

I consume interface:

```
public class Class1 : IMyInter
{
   public ObservableCollection<Data> files{ get; private set; }

   void DoSomething()
   {
       files = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
       files.Add(new Data());
       files.Add(new Data());
   }
}
```

Why in Class2 there is still possibility to Add() since in interface files can be only get? The target is Class2 should be able only to read collection and not to modify it.

```
public class Class2
{
   Class2(IMyInter inter)
   {
       inter.files.Add(new Data());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`ObservableCollection<Data> files { get; }` says that consumers are only allowed to get that property, and they can't set it. However once they've got it, they can do whatever they like to it.

So this is not allowed:

```
inter.files = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
```

But this is:

```
var files = inter.files;
```

And once they've got `files`, they can `.Add()` or `.Clear()`, or anything else.

If you want to stop people from being able to modify the collection, you need to expose something which can't be modified. In this case, that is probably either [`IReadOnlyList<Data>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Data>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlyobservablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), depending on whether you want consumers to be able to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event.

Therefore you might want code which looks like this:

```
public interface IMyInter
{
    ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Data> files { get; }
}

public class Class1 : IMyInter
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Data> _files = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Data> files { get; } = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Data>(_files);

    void DoSomething()
    {
         _files.Add(new Data());
    }
}
```

Notice how I've made `_files` readonly, so there is only ever one instance of `ObservableCollection` assigned to it. I then create a single `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` which wraps it, and is exposed to consumers. When I want to add items, I add them to `_files`.

If we allowed `_files` to be re-assigned to, then `files` could end up referring to an old `ObservableCollection` which we were no longer using, and consumers wouldn't see the latest data. If we generated a new `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` every time a consumer accessed `files`, then that would be unnecessary work, and go against the guidelines for creating properties.

Comment: This is the correct, and most effective, answer provided

Comment: the objective is in Class1 which implements interface i want to be able to create new collection and add items to it but in Class2 i wan only to read it. What should i do?

Comment: @abc See the end of my answer.

Comment: Because what I've learned objects should be only visible/used according to their needs. So for instance if i want to say Class1 can do whatever it want for objectX but Class2 should only see/do only get without set because that's not the duty of Class2.

Comment: @abc that's fine, and is easily achieved. Please see the code example at the end of my answer for the way to do this.

Comment: so i do not get what for is private set; is it only for prevent make new ?? Since i thought this private set is saying you cannot set it (make new) or add to it.

Comment: @abc No, `private set` means you cannot assign to that property, as I explain at the beginning of my answer. It does not put any restrictions on what you can do with the value of the property once you get it. If the value of the property is mutable, then you can mutate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlyobservablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

There is a difference here between a read-only property, the reference to the object is read only, and the semantics of the collection itself. In your case, you can not over-write the reference, but the object itself is mutable.

If you want the other class to only access the collection as a readonly collection, but still get all the events, you will have to create your own interface as one does not exist in C#. You can then create an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). I like using this pattern so I can keep everything dependant on abstractions and not specifics.

```
public interface IReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> 
    : INotifyCollectionChanged, IReadOnlyCollection<T> { }

public class ReadOnlyObservableCollectionAdapter<T> : IReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> 
{ 
    private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> _collection

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollectionAdapter(ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> collection) 
    { 
        _collection = collection;
    }

    ... Add all your adaptive methods here, and expose this in your classes interface.
}

public interface IMyInter
{
    IReadOnlyObservableCollection<Data> files { get; }
}
```

Comment: I cant use this because in class1 i am initializing this (new) and also adding items to it. but in Class2 i would like only to have opton to read it.

Comment: You will have to either use the example from @canton7 or you could create your own interface that inherits `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `IReadOnlyCollection` and create an adapter class that wraps it up yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The access modifier only defines changing/setting the reference.

With a private set, you cannot change `files` to be a reference to something else.

However as it's a collection, you can 'get' `files` and then perform any operations on it.

Consider that you don't know if `.Add()` is any different from `.Potatoes()` or any other method on the object you might wish to call.

`.Add()` does not change `files`, it does something inside the object.